# Can one use Stream.Position to track upload progress without causing issues?

Tags: c#, stream, blazor, minio

I'm using a MinIO S3 file server to store user data of my blazor server side application. Since users are working with datasets for some ML applications, quite a lot of files need to be updated.

**Initial Issue**

I'm stating my initial issue, just for completeness and to avoid creating a y/x problem post (However, I'm curious about my attempted solution in any case):
I'm using a hidden `<InputFile/>` and some javascript  to create a drop area for the files the user wants to upload. Problem is that if more then ~200-250 files are dropped (i.e. `OnChange` event with those files is triggered), the blazor circuit breaks.

**Attempted Solution**

My solution was rather simple: Force the user to upload zipped files with the completed dataset, if the file count is >150.

**New Problem**

For long running upload operations I need some user feedback. For single files the upload is fast enough to have some GUI changes after each file, but the MinIO .NET client doesn't seem to have any way to know the progress of a single file upload.

Here is the current code for a single file upload:

```
public async Task StoreImage(ImageDatabaseModel image, Stream dataStream, string contentType, long fileSize)
{
    await CreateBucketIfNotExists(image.UserID);
    PutObjectArgs args = new PutObjectArgs()
        .WithBucket(image.UserID)
        .WithObject(GetMinioImageName(image))
        .WithStreamData(dataStream)
        .WithContentType(contentType)
        .WithObjectSize(fileSize);

    await _minio.PutObjectAsync(args);
}
```

My idea is was now to use the stream to get the progress information. Here is to code of an initial test:

```
public async Task StoreZibFile(ImageDatabaseModel image, Stream dataStream, string contentType, long fileSize)
{
    // never mind I'm still uploading an image, this is only for testing anyway
    await CreateBucketIfNotExists(image.UserID);
    PutObjectArgs args = new PutObjectArgs()
        .WithBucket(image.UserID)
        .WithObject(GetMinioImageName(image))
        .WithStreamData(dataStream)
        .WithContentType(contentType)
        .WithObjectSize(fileSize);

    var t1 = _minio.PutObjectAsync(args);
    var t2 = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (dataStream.Position < fileSize)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dataStream.Position);
            await Task.Delay(500); 
        }

    });

    await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);
}
```

This gives the expected output of the `dataStream.Position` value rising during the upload.
The question is: Is this approach suitable for my usecase? Are there any downsides I'm unaware of?

Comment: It's probably fine.  Technically streams aren't threadsafe by default, but the worst case scenario here is just getting an inaccurate value for `Position` since reading from that property shouldn't mutate any data.

Comment: @KirkWoll Thanks for the information. If you want to put this comment as answer for future readers, I'm happy to tag it. Additionally, do you have any input on my initial problem, or do you recommend to force the user to zip data anyway?